# Algorithm to generate numbers and their prime factors?

Tags: prime-factorization

Similarly to how there are far better sieving algorithms to generate prime numbers than checking each number, are there any known/common algorithms to generate numbers *and* their factors rather than factoring each number?

Comment: You can easily modify the sieve of Eratosthenes to store the prime factors of the composite numbers while you're sieving for primes. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, that is what I meant, thanks

Comment: Ok. The simplest way is to just store the smallest prime factor in the array. So in slot $n$ you store $p$. If $p=n$ then $n$ is prime. Otherwise, $n$ is composite, with factors $p$ and $n/p$, and then you look in slot $n/p$ to see what *it's* smallest prime factor is.